# Binary integer programming with PULP using vector syntax for variables?

Tags: python, pulp

New to the python library PULP and I'm finding the documentation somewhat unhelpful, as it does not include examples using lists of variables. I've tried to create an absolutely minimalist example below to illustrate my confusion.

```
import pulp
IDENTIFIERS = ['A','B','C','D','E']
PRICES      = dict( zip( IDENTIFIERS, [100.0, 99.0, 100.5, 101.5, 200.0 ] ) )
n           = len( IDENTIFIERS )

x     = pulp.LpVariable.dicts( "x", indexs = IDENTIFIERS, lowBound=0, upBound=1, cat='Integer', indexStart=[] )
prob  = pulp.LpProblem( "Minimalist example", pulp.LpMaximize )
prob += pulp.lpSum( [ x[i]*PRICES[i] for i in IDENTIFIERS ]  ), " Objective is sum of prices of selected items "
prob += pulp.lpSum( [ x[i] for i in IDENTIFIERS ] )==2, " Constraint is that we choose two items "
prob.solve()
for ident in IDENTIFIERS:
    if x[ident]==1:
        print ident + " is in the basket "
```

The output is:

```
A is in the basket 
B is in the basket 
C is in the basket 
D is in the basket 
E is in the basket
```

The optimizer is not recognizing the constraint that we only add two values.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'll leave this here in case anyone else is just as silly, but actually the above example works fine. I had merely failed to examine the results correctly. Instead:

```
def printProb( prob ):
    for v in prob.variables():
       print v.name, "=", v.varValue
    print "Status:", pulp.LpStatus[ prob.status ]
```

reveals that the solution is correct.

Comment: You may accept your own answer if it solves your problem. This helps other in filtering unanswered questions.