# Python equivalent to R's lpSolve for Linear Programming

Tags: python, linear-programming, lpsolve

I'm converting code from R to Python and am looking for some help with the easiest way to solve a linear programming problem. I've been searching for a long time, and there doesn't seem to be a consensus on the best module to use.

In this example I simply want to select 3 of 5 options, maximizing `obj`, while making sure that the constraint columns are above 0:

```
obj = [np.random.uniform(0, 100) for _ in range(5)]
col1 = [1] * 5
col2 = [np.random.uniform(0, 100) for _ in range(5)]
col3 = [np.random.uniform(0, 100) for _ in range(5)]
col4 = [np.random.uniform(0, 100) for _ in range(5)]
col5 = [np.random.uniform(0, 100) for _ in range(5)]
col6 = [np.random.uniform(0, 100) for _ in range(5)]

ConstraintMatrix = pd.DataFrame(data = {'col1': col1, 'col2': col2, 'col3': col3, 'col4': col4, 'col5': col5, 'col6': col6})
ConstraintDirections = ['==', '>=', '>=', '>=', '>=', '>=']
ConstraintValues = [3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

In R to get the 3 items that maximize the objective, I would simply run:

```
library(lpSolve)
sol <- lpSolve::lp("max",
                   objective.in = obj,
                   const.mat    = t(ConstraintMatrix), # Transpose matrix
                   const.dir    = ConstraintDirections,
                   const.rhs    = ConstraintValues,
                   all.bin      = T # decision variables are all binary
)

ConstraintMatrix$selected <- sol$solution[1:nrow(ConstraintMatrix)]
ConstraintMatrix <- ConstraintMatrix[ConstraintMatrix$selected == 1,]
```

Obviously this problem doesn't need linear programming to solve, but it illustrates what I'm looking for from Python in order to solve my much larger problem. Is there a Python function that takes an Objective, Constraint Matrix, Direction Vector, and Value Vector and spits out a solution just like my `lpSolve:lp`?

Answer (score 0):

I guess [Pulp](https://pythonhosted.org/PuLP/index.html) would serve you well.

As you're trying to solve binary problem, check the following:

1. Pulp's [set partitioning example](https://pythonhosted.org/PuLP/CaseStudies/a_set_partitioning_problem.html)
2. Pulp's [Sudoku example](https://pythonhosted.org/PuLP/CaseStudies/a_sudoku_problem.html)
3. Relevant [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31410972/binary-integer-programming-with-pulp-using-vector-syntax-for-variables)

Comment: Also worth checking is pyomo

Comment: @abhiieor Wow, I've never heard about this one. Looks nice. Thanks!